# How to find/list the directories where a particular sub-directory is not present

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a shell script where it is checking if the bin directory is present under all the users directory under /home directory. The bin directory can be present directly under user directory or under the child directory of the user directory.
I mean let say I have a user as amit under /home. So the bin directory can be present directly as /amit/bin or can be present as /amit/jash/bin

Now my requirement is that I should have a list of users directories where the bin directory is not present either directly under user directory or under the child directory of the user directory. I tried the command as :
**find /home -type d ! -exec test -e '{}/bin' \; -print**
but it is not working. However when I am replacing the bin directory with some file, the command is working fine. Looks like this command is particularly for files. Is there any similar command for directories?? Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. The catch is that your test of "does the following directory NOT exist in this target" can't be expressed within find's conditions in such a way as to return only the top-level directory. So you need to nest, one way or another.

One strategy would be to use a for loop in bash:

```
$ mkdir foo bar baz one two
$ mkdir bar/bin baz/bin
$ for d in /home/*/; do find "$d" -type d -name bin | grep -q . || echo "$d"; done
foo/
one/
two/
```

This uses pathname expansion (globbing) to generate the list of directories to test, and then checks for the existence of "bin".  If that check fails (i.e. find outputs nothing), the directory is printed. Note the trailing slash on `/home/*/`, which ensures that you will only be searching within directories, rather than files that might accidentally exist in `/home/`.

---

Another possibility might be to use nested `find`s, if you don't want to depend on bash:

```
$ find /home/ -type d -depth 1 -not -exec sh -c "find {}/ -type d -name bin -print | grep -q . " \; -print
/home/foo
/home/one
/home/two
```

This roughly duplicates the effect of the bash `for` loop above, but by nesting `find` within `find -exec`. It uses `grep -q .` to convert the output of `find` into an exit status that can be used as a condition for the *outer* `find`.

Note that since you're looking for a *bin directory*, we want to use `test -d` rather than `test -e` (which would also check for a bin *file*, which probably does not matter to you.)

---

Another option is to use bash process redirection.  On multiple lines for easier reading:

```
cd /home/
comm -3 \
  <(printf '%s\n' */ | sed 's|/.*||' | sort) \
  <(find */ -type d -name bin | cut -d/ -f1 | uniq)
```

This unfortunately requires you to change to the `/home` directory before running, because of the way it strips off subdirectories. You can of course collapse this into a big long one-liner if you feel so inclined.

This `comm` solution also has the risk of failing on directories with special characters in their names, like newlines.

---

One last option is bash-only but more than a one-liner. It involves subtracting the directories containing "bin" from the full list. It uses an associative array and `globstar`, so it depends on bash version 4.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar

# Go to our root
cd /home

# Declare an associative array
declare -A dirs=()

# Populate the array with our "full" list of home directories
for d in */; do dirs[${d%/}]=""; done

# Remove directories that contain a "bin" somewhere inside 'em
for d in **/bin; do unset dirs[${d%%/*}]; done

# Print the result in reproducible form
declare -p dirs

# Or print the result just as a list of words.
printf '%s\n' "${!dirs[@]}"
```

Note that we're storing directories in the array *index*, which (1) makes it easy for us to find and delete items, and (2) insures unique entries, even if one user has multiple "bin" directories under their home.

Comment: apology for late reply and thanks a lot for providing multiple solutions. I went with the second solution and it worked. However I was getting error initially:   **find: warning: you have specified the -depth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-depth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments** However after interchanging the positions of -type d and -depth 1 and modifying depth  with maxdepth it worked.

Comment: Interesting. That's not an error I get when I run the command in OSX or FreeBSD. Odd that the warning about options not being positional is resolved by changing the position of the options! :-)  Actually, it turns out that `-depth` is the only problem, switching to `-maxdepth` makes the order unimportant. Turns out in FreeBSD (where I tested), `-depth n` is equivalent to `-maxdepth n`, but Linux doesn't have this functionality. Thanks for mentioning it, and I'm glad I could help. Please feel free to click the checkmark to the left of the answer to "close" this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /home
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name . | sort > a
find . -type d -name bin | cut -d/ -f1,2 | sort > b
comm -23 a b
```

Here, I'm making two sorted lists.  The first contains all the home directories, and the second contains the top parent of any bin subdirectory.  Finally I output any items from the first list not present in the second.